# dojo/_base/*js missing from worklight apk in wl 6.1

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have a hybrid app that was created with WL 6.1 that uses the included dojolib.  Currently it is in production for iphone and we are adding the android flavor of it.  When running the code from the mobile simulator on the console, both the android and iphone work fine.  The ipa file works fine.  When I run the hybrid on an android device (Samsung S4), the application throws errors in the log on app startup.  I have the "provide dojo libraries" turned off.    In the DDMS log I see statements like the following:

```
09-09 12:47:12.092: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(20324): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/_base/declare.js
09-09 12:47:12.263: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(20324): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/_base/connect.js
09-09 12:47:12.303: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(20324): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/_base/event.js
```

Looking out in the android project in eclipse, I see those files in the "assets/www/default/dojo/_base" directory.  The issue is when I look in the APK file, the "_base" directory is not there.  Any help as to understanding why it is missing?

Comment: In your project do these files exist in the www directory?

Comment: yes, they are in the "project/www/dojo/_base" directory.  The only place I've not been able to find them is in the apk file.

Comment: inside of the .settings folder there is a file com.ibm.imp.worklight.core.prefs is there an entry for your project. ex...toolkit/apps/<appname>/dojo=true

Comment: yes, it is set to true.  I did a test and copied the same directory (_base) in assets/www/default/dojo to "base" and it shows up.  I tried giving a few other new directories in there.  Any directory that starts with an underscore, is dropped from the apk.

Comment: You are right, my program does not add those files either, but they should not be need because the declarations of those functions exist in core-web-layer.js

Comment: so why is it trying to open them?  This is only happening on android.  On ios, no errors and works fine.

Comment: I found a few items on the google android ADK forums.  This is a known bug with the apkbuilder and subsequent tools that copy the files into the apk.  It is currently hardcoded to exclude folders called CVS, SCCS, META_INF, .svn, and anything that starts with a '_'.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be using the compiled version of the dojo files, it seem that its not.
i would check

1. These files : core-web-layer.js and mobile-ui-layer are in your www folder
2. That the wlCommonInit function includes below:

   function wlCommonInit() {
       require([ "layers/core-web-layer", "layers/mobile-ui-layer" ], dojoInit);
   }

Comment: We have those, but there are classes that we are using that is not part of those layers.  I spoke with the WL dev team and their suggestion was to use the Dojo build tool and create a new layer for the parts that are not there.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found an alternative way to get around the android packaging bug.  As I mentioned earlier one way is to use the DojoBuildFactory to create a new layer that would have the files imbedded in them.  This is the same process that WL uses to create the core-web-layer and mobile-ui-layer.  I have a team working on this, but the documentation is ... scant and it is a time consuming process.

While they were doing that, I found what I think is a cleaner way of addressing the issue.  Effectively open up an unsigned apk, insert the files, and then sign the APK.  Worked like a charm.  Here are the steps I used:

- Build from working pointing to the correct worklight server and with the provide missing dojo libraries turned off
- Export as Android project as an unsigned apk
- Open command prompt with right env settings pointing to JDK and ADT
- Create keystore (if not already done)
- Unpack into temp using jar
- Copy dojo files over from android/native/www/default
- Pack back into apk using jar
- Sign the jar
- Zipalign the jar

Now you have a working apk that includes the files/directories in asset that begin with a "_".